# click back button to stop playing audio issue

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am having one weird issue.In a grid view cell,each cell contains one word audio song.

While pressing back button it automatically chose one cell and play that one word song.

My only need is,it wouldn't have to chose that one cell and it wouldn't have to play that song while clicking the back button.

I have posted the below relevant code:

```
 @Override
 public void onPause() {

 if (getActivity().isFinishing()){ //basically BACK was pressed from this activity
    player.stop();

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "YOU PRESSED BACK FROM YOUR 'HOME/MAIN' ACTIVITY", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

  }

  Context context = getActivity();

  ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
  List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);

  if (!taskInfo.isEmpty()) {
    ComponentName topActivity = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;

    if (!topActivity.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
        player.stop();

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "YOU LEFT YOUR APP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "YOU SWITCHED ACTIVITIES WITHIN YOUR APP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  }
super.onPause();
 }
```

Anyone can help me with this.Thank you.

Comment: try to write your music player code in service

Comment: @rajahsekar where it is?

Comment: when click back button activity will finish ... it is better to write music player code in service http://sapandiwakar.in/tutorial-how-to-manually-create-android-media-player-controls/

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't sure what's your objective, but guess you should do your coding in onBackPressed() instead.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
     // code here to do stuff
     super.onBackPressed();  // default back action, optional depending on your needs
}
```

I don't think onPause() should be used this way, take a look at the Android Activity Lifecycle, it's a basic for Android development. Cheers

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html